# choosing static site generator

Tags: python, static-site

Currently I have my website generated from markdown files by Jekyll. In general this works, but I would prefer a generator which:

- is written in python. I'm familiar with python but I don't know Ruby and thus it's easier for me to solve Python-related issues such as installation, modules, etc. I would consider a non-Pythonic tool only if its self contained, which does not clutter my disk with yet another package manager etc.
- is more flexible. My site is not a blog and the Jekyll's directory scheme (named after post date) drives me crazy
- makes links to static content easier. I link many *.PDF files on my site, making these links in Jekyll is tedious
- makes it easy to style the pages with CSS
- and finally, of course I need the tool to be matured and well-documented.

Answer (score 0):

**Pelican** https://github.com/getpelican/pelican

- written in Python
- pretty flexible
- styling is very straightforward
- very well documented
- most popular open source Python static site gen (number of GitHub stars/forks to date)